# Is there any linux command to speed up the execution of the files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, perl, performance

I would like to know if there is any linux command to execute the perl file faster?

I used the following command to check execution time:

`time ./rspd.pl`

output:

```
1.003u 0.480s 3:34.90 0.6% 0+0k 56+5520io 0pf+0w
```

Some of my perl scripts take long time to finishIn such cases can I use any other linux command to make the execution faster?

Comment: Possible to tune your perl script, or post it here for review ?

Comment: No. Just ask a question (probably on [so]) asking how you can improve your script. We can't help without knowing what the script does.

Comment: @steve, no.  We're not [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  But, subroutine, since it sounds like the Perl script *is* actually working correctly (not in need of debugging, just tuning), you can get quite excellent code review if you post it up on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).  Read their FAQ and guidelines first, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only answer is **no**. There is no such generic command to speed up another arbitrary executable like your perl script.

To make your `rspd.pl` faster you should know first what it is doing at all. Why is it slow? CPU, RAM, Network or disk I/O? This is called 'profiling', see for example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371714/how-do-i-profile-my-perl-programs

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

Generally speaking, no. You can't do that.

However, sometimes you can. For example, let's say that you have a program which makes some advanced operations on strings and changes each line, independantly. Then, you could use GNU `parallel` - the program designed to run programs in parallel.

However, you need to know *what* your program does, and what is the bottleneck. Some programs divide themselves into smaller subprocesses by default, so you would get no speedup. Some programs use disc heavily, and since that is the bottleneck, you would get no improvement. Some programs have a logic which can't be used on the divided files.

GNU Parallel divides the file into smaller parts and runs the script on each part, merging the results. This works fine if you run something like `awk` which changes first and second column. This works not that good when you run a program that changes `dog` to N, where N is how many times you have seen the word `dog` so far.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The best you can do is use a command to distribute in different threads and therefore maybe different cores, making it run faster. For example, take a look at [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score -2):

Store all perl libraries in ram, so the execution will be faster when a perl script use a lot of them.

Comment: You mean with a `tmpfs` partition?

Comment: I don't know why they're downvoting your answer, it's actually a good approach. I would also put the target files into a `tmpfs`if there are any.

Comment: The question shows that the script needs more than 3 minutes wall time but only 1 second CPU time. This slowness is certainly not caused by loading perl modules.